# 405 Method Not Allowed ngrok для axios.post запроса

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel, axios

В приложении на `laravel` отправляю `post` запрос на адрес который возвращает `json` объект. Когда я запускал приложение на локальном сервере `php artisan serve`, `post` запрос из-за `http` естественно не разрешался. Чтобы исправить это я запустил `ngrok` сервер у которого есть защищенное соединение, но даже так код ошибки остается тот же
**штука если тыкнуть на ключик на адресной строке:**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Запрос выглядит так:**

```js
axios.post("/modal-info", { id: 1 })
    .then(async res => {
        console.log(await res)
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
    })
```

**консоль ngrok:**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

*P.S. `axios.get("/modal-info").then(...)` возвращает объект с адреса успешно*

*P.S. оставлю открытым пару часов https://c1597888ac87.ngrok.io*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для начала не забыть в `web.php` изменить `Route::get` на `Route::post`, после отправить `csrf` ключ в заголовке запроса, вот так:

```js
axios.post("/modal-info", {
    id: 1,
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': document.getElementById("csrf_token").getAttribute("content") // на странице есть <meta id="csrf_token" name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    }
})
    .then(async res => {
        console.log(await res)
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
    })
```

[ссылка на этот момент в документации](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token)